# How to turn an Array of sentences into an array of Words? (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have an Array with several sentences and I want to change the Array so each word is an item.

Right now the console log of the array looks like this:

```
[
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
'Sed faucibus mattis odio, eu rhoncus ante porttitor sit amet',
'Pellentesque ac elementum diam',
'Ut sagittis faucibus ante, et egestas erat maximus vitae'
]
```

I want it to be like:

```
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', ...etc]
```

I tried using the `split()` method, but then it creates several arrays inside the original array with the split words of each sentence.
What's the best way to do it?

Comment: just `join` them and then split `.join(' ').split(/\W+/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const arr = [
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
  "Sed faucibus mattis odio, eu rhoncus ante porttitor sit amet",
  "Pellentesque ac elementum diam",
  "Ut sagittis faucibus ante, et egestas erat maximus vitae",
];

const result = arr.flatMap((str) => str.split(" "));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

After split, you have a multilevel array. What you would want to do is [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) your array.

```
let ans = q.map((a)=>{
  return a.split(' ');
}).flat();
```

As pointed out by @Reyno, this can be achieved using flatMap() too:

`let ans = q.flatMap(a => a.split(' '));`

Comment: FYI: map and flat can be combined with [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) `q.flatMap(a => a.split(' '));`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
'Sed faucibus mattis odio, eu rhoncus ante porttitor sit amet',
'Pellentesque ac elementum diam',
'Ut sagittis faucibus ante, et egestas erat maximus vitae'
];

const out = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  return a.concat(b.split(" "));
}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Note that I prefer the answer by Tushar Shahi, even better if the comment on his post is used.

Comment: Is `amet,` a word?

Comment: It's a string of characters. Are you trying to say you wanted punctuation removed?